# Change text from input id

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to change the text of whatever is existing with whatever is typed in the input. I try to take it from the id="text" but it doesn't work and just displays text.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="Type your text here.....">

<div class="form-group">
    <button>submit</button>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="response">
    <pre>Type some text in the above text field, then log the text out here on button click</pre>
</div>


<script>
    $('button').click(function() {
        $("#response").text("#text");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$("#response").text($("#text").val());`

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $('button').click(function() {
 
    $("#response").text($("#text").val());
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="Type your text here.....">        

  <div class="form-group">
    <button>submit</button>
  </div>  
  <div class="form-group" id="response">
    <pre>Type some text in the above text field, then log the text out here on button click</pre>
  </div>  



<script>
 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="Type your text here.....">        

  <div class="form-group">
    <button>submit</button>
  </div>  
  <div class="form-group" id="response">
    <pre>Type some text in the above text field, then log the text out here on button click</pre>
  </div>  



<script>
  $('button').click(function() {
    $("#response").text($("#text").val());
});
</script>
```

Use `$("#text").val()` to get value from input

Answer (score 0):

As of now you are just passing string `#text` thus it is displayed. Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)to get the value from `input`, then set it.

```
 $("#response").text($("#text").val());
```